# Unresolved library: AppiumLibrary

Tags: appium, robotframework, python-appium

When generating libspec, I am getting this error:

> Importing library 'AppiumLibrary' failed: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'appium.webdriver.common.touch_action'
> Consider adding the needed paths to the "robot.pythonpath" setting
> and calling the "Robot Framework: Clear caches and restart" action.robotframework

I have tried a number of solutions with my information such as:

- Appium version: 2.0.1
- Python version: 3.9.6
- Robotframework version: 7.0
- robotframework-appiumlibrary version: 2.0.0

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in AppiumLibrary and how it handles its dependencies. It pulls in python appium bindings that have stuff deprecated that AppiumLibrary still expects to be present.

Fix:

`pip install --force-reinstall "Appium-Python-Client<4.0.0"`

I've filed an issue and pull request to fix it:

- https://github.com/serhatbolsu/robotframework-appiumlibrary/issues/417
- https://github.com/serhatbolsu/robotframework-appiumlibrary/pull/418